# I cant select the delete class in my jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

```
<div class="dvThumb">
    <div class="comp" data-compprice=<?php echo$saleprice = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_sale_price', true); ?>>
        <!--added for delete-->

        <div class='hover-btn'>
            <button class='close_fast'>
                <span aria-hidden='true'  class='close_fast2'>×</span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <!--added for delete-->
        <div class="dvTowelStack">

            <div class="dvwel"></div>
            <div class="dvwel"></div>
            <div class="dvwel"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="dottom"></div>

    </div>

    <img src="<?php echo $image[0];?>" />
    <p><?php echo the_title(); ?></p>
</div>
```

I am trying to implement a onhover delete option .. but when i click ,,nothing happens..probably the selection part of jquery has a problem.Following is jquery i tired

```
$(".hover-btn .close_fast").click(function(event){
    alert("delete ?");
}); 

$(".hover-btn .close_fast .close_fast2").on('click',function(event){
    alert("delete ?");
}); 

$(".close_fast2").on('click',function(event){
    alert("delete ?");
}); 

$(".close_fast").on('click',function(event){
    alert("delete ?");
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".close_fast").on('click',function(event){
        alert("delete ?");
    });
});
```

not even one worked.

But it works on fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/rc0tscd4/3/
please tell me where i am going wrong
NOTE : this full html is gets added on drag and drop into container using `append` method . Does append method compiles too or it just adds the html?

Comment: did you wrap your code inside `$(document).ready`?

Comment: This is confusing, do you want event on `hover` or on `click`? And what do you mean by "I can't select the delete class in my jquery"? I don't see any attempt to do this.

Comment: And start by doing what @KhanhTO said, wrap you js in `$(function(){ //you code });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said:

> NOTE : this full html is gets added on drag and drop into container

I'm quite sure that delegated event handlers would help: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Try:

```
$(document).on("click",".hover-btn .close_fast",function(event){
     alert("delete ?");
 }); 

 $(document).on('click', ".hover-btn .close_fast .close_fast2", function(event){
     alert("delete ?");
 }); 

 $(document).on('click',".close_fast2",function(event){
     alert("delete ?");
 }); 

 $(document).on('click',".close_fast",function(event){
     alert("delete ?");
 });
```

**Note**: for better performance, you should replace `document` with your container so that the bubbling takes less levels to go up.

**Explanation of your problem:**

As you append your html dynamically, the newly created DOM objects don't have the event handlers attached because the code that attaches the handler **has already run**.

With delegated event handlers, you attach your event handlers to the parent element **that exists at the time we run the code** (it's `document` in this case). When the child elements are clicked (no event handlers), the event is bubbled up by browser and is handled by its parent (with event handlers attached)

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers

Comment: wow .. this was the problem.. can you explain me why dat happend

Comment: @Yo Yo: see my explanation.

Comment: Thanks thats well explained